# Is there any Decorator class in Java library?

Tags: java, decorator

I wondering is there any class or interface in Java library what i can use as Decorator-pattern or any 3rd party library you recommend. I already know i can do it for my own, but i'm looking for something similar to show in a class.

Comment: The whole java.io package (Stream, Writer) is a good example

Comment: Are you looking for something like JLayer? (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like JLayer http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html